# WPF LiveChart rendering from usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I´m trying to render a Cartesian Chart from a usercontrol.
The textblock just renders fine but unfortunately the chart isn`t shown.
I´ve no clue how to fix this. Could anybody give me a hint?

This is the function for rendering the graph and save it as a pngfile.

```
public void ConvertGraph(Object dataContext)
        {
            UserControl ucGraph = new Graph
            {
                DataContext = dataContext
            };
            ucGraph.Measure(new Size(400, 400));
            ucGraph.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(400, 400)));
            ucGraph.UpdateLayout();

            RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(400, 400, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            
            bmp.Render(ucGraph);

            var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

            using (Stream stm = File.Create(@"c:\Temp\test.png"))
                encoder.Save(stm);

        }
```

This is the UserControl.

```
<UserControl x:Class="LogAnalyzerWpf.Views.PrintViews.Graph"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LogAnalyzerWpf.Views.PrintViews"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:LogAnalyzerWpf.ViewModels"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             Background="White">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding HighLevelAlarm}"></TextBlock>
        
        <lvc:CartesianChart DisableAnimations="True" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" LegendLocation="Bottom" Series="{Binding seriesCollection}">
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis Title="Date" Labels="{Binding DateTimeValues}"></lvc:Axis>
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis Title="Temperature (°C)"/>
                <lvc:Axis Title="Level (mm)" Position="RightTop" />
            </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        </lvc:CartesianChart>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by making a couple of changes.

1. In your `ConvertGraph` method, change `UserControl ucGraph = new Graph` to be `Graph ucGraph = new Graph`
2. In your xaml, give your `lvc:CartesianChart` a name like `x:Name="chart"`
3. In your `ConvertGraph` method, right before you call `ucGraph.UpdateLayout()`, also call `ucGraph.chart.Update(true,true);` which will force it to redraw itself

Instructions outlined here: https://github.com/Live-Charts/Live-Charts/blob/develop/Examples/Wpf/CartesianChart/Chart%20to%20Image/ChartToImageSample.xaml.cs

As a side note, I'd also recommend setting `DisableAnimations` on the chart to be `true`, so that it doesn't mess with your renders while saving (might be important if the chart is complicated).